# Pseudo li element disappears after adding backgroundcolor

Tags: css, html-lists, element

I'm trying to fix a problem with a pseudo li element in this script:

http://jsfiddle.net/5xkrS/6/

When adding a backgroundcolor to the parent div, the connectorbars between the stepnumbers disappear. (see http://jsfiddle.net/5xkrS/7/ )

The backgroundcolor seems to overrule the pseudo li element, but not the li element. Using the following css:

```
/*progressbar connectors*/

#progressbar li:after {
    content:"";
    width: 100%;
    height: 2px;
    background: white;
    position: absolute;
    left: -50%;
    top: 9px;
    z-index: -1; /*put it behind the numbers*/
}
```

What can cause this problem and is there a way to fix this?

Comment: you have `z-index: -1` which effectively puts it behind the background colour

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go

http://jsfiddle.net/5xkrS/9/

```
#container {
    width: 500px;
    height: 600px;
    margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
    background-color: deepskyblue;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Added `position` relative and `z-index` 1 to the container. tested on FF and chrome on mac